# ESlint rule that detects that a variable and a function has the same name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, scope, eslint

I happened to name a variable the same as a function in Node.js. This did not go very well, Node 10 did not like it. And since this was a hook function (not called from the UI of the app) it took some time before I discovered what went wrong.

Is there some ESLint rule that can discover these type of bugs? This is under Firebase and and ESLint is run during the deploy to production server.

The actual conflicting use of the variable name was in the same block, something like this: `const a = a(x)`.

Comment: what was the name of the function in node?

Comment: What you want is eslint and a lint rule. Look it up. It's a node package for dev and can statically anaylize source files. Ultimately you just want a linting tool. Also asking for a tool goes against stack overflow's rules.

Comment: @ehab A very specific name. I just happened to get it wrong during cut-and-paste. VS Code is unfortunately terrible some times and you can't see what is going on. (But I don't have time to use another editor now.)

Comment: @Leo In case you want to know people are voting to close as the question asks for a tool or library or an off site link, which is out of scope to for SO, ( even though i didn't voted )

Comment: @RichardBarker Thanks. I use eslint and thought it would discover this. It did not. That is why I am asking. What do I miss?

Comment: Use ESLint *with what rules*? https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow?

Comment: The correct linting rule is what you missed. Thanks jon for providing that link!

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks, I know. But if those who do not like the question does not want to contribute (just destroy) then I will not find a way to ask for this. How do I ask? (I thought there was some ESlint rule.)

Comment: @Leo Might be as simple as renaming the question from "tool that detects..." to "how to write a ESLint rule for..."  A lot of people on Stack Overflow don't read into the actual question before voting to close.  They read the literal text, vote, and move on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ESlint has barked at me quite often. But not this time. Is this rule not on by default?

Comment: @Leo well here are some short of things i follow before i ask a question, 1) try myself untill unless i feel now i have done all i can do and couldn't proceed further, 2) try to do some research on google, SO or any other related site, 3) if i still couldn't solve then i write down all what i did to reach 3rd step and then frame it to question and ask here.

To be honest it seems to missing the effort and research part, anyways you will always find people will lead you in right direction

Comment: No rules are on by default, and according to https://eslint.org/docs/rules/ no-shadow isn't enabled by eslint:recommend either.

Comment: @CodeManiac That is good, but hard to do for things you are not familiar with. I am not familiar with ESlint. I just hope it will help me. And I expect it to not be overly friendly and instead bark at me a bit more often than necessary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I actually ended up with something like `const a = a(x)`. It is not the usual shadowing, it is ambiguous use of the variable name. Is there an ESLint rule for this?

Comment: @RichardBarker I think I still miss the correct ESLint rule. Is there some rule that fits this?

Comment: @RichardBarker Thanks, that is a good idea. As I tried to say above the assumption you made about the rule pointed to is false. There is no rule in ESLint for this problem. Or, at least I can't find it.

Comment: And again, someone deleted my comments about conduct. Would that person please step forward and explain why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a tool like this *could* exist for JavaScript, as JavaScript doesn't really disambiguate the type of object assigned to the variable.

```
function a() {

}
```

... is basically equivalent to:

```
var a = function () {

};
```

Additionally, the value of `a` in this example can be reassigned later.

A linter may help you, and there may be some help in some IDEs, but they won't truly know the intention of the programmer.

Comment: I know, but a tool could warn for conflicting declarations.

Comment: @Leo For that, consider `let` and `const`.

Comment: I actually ended up with something like `const a = a(x)`. Don't ask me how, but I usually do not wait for VS Code to display. I normally know what I am doing (in editors I trus...). But a pattern like my code above is perhaps easy to detect? It is not the usual shadowing, it is ambiguous use of the variable name.

Comment: @Leo If that's what you did, then you should have a syntax error on your console.

Comment: Yes, there was of course. But it took some time before I found it. (There are delays on the sending site etc. I did not know where to look.) But a powerful linter could detect it. (This is analogous to asking the compiler to check the code from the editor.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [no-redeclare](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare) rule you can set in *ESLint*, which tells you the problematic line in your code.

```
/*eslint no-redeclare: "error"*/

function a() {}
const a = a();

=> 4:5  error  'a' is already defined  no-redeclare
```

Also *ESLint* will raises an error with the [standard](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard/blob/eb187deec36e72bfea4034db1a81b0d7414f814a/eslintrc.json#L136) configuration.

```
function a() {}
var a = a();

=> 4:5  error  Parsing error: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

Of course, with `const`, you will get a syntax error with the line as well if you try to run your script.

Comment: Thanks, but ESLint did not catch this error. I don't think I have changed much in ESLint configuration (since as you can see I am quite unaware of how to configure ESLint). Now I wonder what configuration `firebase deploy` uses for ESLint (and where I can see that).

Comment: Don't know much about _Firebase_ but I guess your _ESLint_ config does not dependent on it, usually you can [customize](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) your own rules in .eslintrc file.